# Solving inequality for all even integers .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am not sure how to show that if $n\equiv 0\pmod 2$ (i.e, $n$ is even) then, $$2(n-1)\leqslant \frac{n(n+2)}{4}$$ Equality holds when $n\leqslant 4,\;n \text{ is even}.$

Comment: To some point it looks obvious, but i am not sure how to prove that..

Comment: What had you tried?

Comment: @zkutch i am trying to make it more clear that the statement holds true.

Comment: How you obtain $n\leqslant 6$?

Comment: Because for n graeter than 6, the equality does not follows.

Comment: Can you write a proof why this is so?

Comment: Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and the community. Some forms of context include background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: @zkutch i have found this manually, not prove this yet. i dont know whether Induction will work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

See this:$$ 2(n - 1) \leqslant \frac{n(n + 2)}{4} \Leftrightarrow 8(n - 1) \leqslant n(n + 2) \Leftrightarrow n^2 - 6n + 8 \geqslant 0 \Leftrightarrow (n - 4)(n - 2) \geqslant 0 $$
then equality holds iff $~n = 2,4$.

Specifically, we can make the equality condition to $0 < n \leqslant 4$. The inequality holds true for each $n \in \mathbb{Z} - \{ 3\}. $